# How to Remove the Self adding TOC and still keeping the \hyperef to the TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

Hey anyone know how to keep the link to TOC due to `\hyperref` but still be using something like `\tabelofcontents*` og \keepFromToc to hide the TOC link in the table of contents.

First time asking here and first time I'm using Latex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please rephrase your question. It's a little bit difficult to understand.  Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It might help if you explained what you mean? Self adding toc in the toc? Is it `\tableofcontents*` you are looking for? As always it is a good idea to provide a minimal example, a self contained document that others can copy and fun on their own systems.

Comment: Hope its better now or let me know if it is'ent.

I cant really provide you whit the \begin and \end since its a really big paper im doing and i somehow made it really difficult. everything is made whit \input even the preamble so dont think it wude make any sense at all. sorry :S

Comment: Then copy the big document into a new file or folder and start removing stuff that is not relevant. I still do not understand what it us you are looking for. So a code example is necessary.

Comment: This is still as clear as mud. Please explain, in detail, what you mean by "self-adding to the ToC" and "keeping `\hyperref` to the ToC". It's not clear at all.

Comment: Sorry. Well i would like when i go to the PDF that i can klick on the ToC on the left side, but when i than look on the ToC in the PDF i dont whant it to count it self in as a ToC line. Does that make any sense?

Comment: @Michael: Ahhh, these are referred to as bookmarks. And yes, [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) automatically inserts a bookmark for every entry into the regular ToC. So you want *only* the bookmarks and *no* visible ToC in your document?

Comment: Well i think you got the ide of what i want, hmm well, i want the bookmarks and i would like to be abule to klick on the bookmark that gets me to the ToC but when i than look on the Toc i dont whant the entry off the "Toc" to be on the list.. If i use \tabelofcontents* the bookmark to the ToC allsow disapears and that one i wude like to stay. :S sorry for the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is still unclear to me, but I understood it this way:

- Add a bookmark to the ToC
- Don't add a ToC entry in the ToC itself.

---

This can be achieved, for example, bu manually adding the bookmark with a `dest=toc::label` (or use a different name.).

Use `\hypertarget{toc::label}{}` with an empty anchor just before `\tableofcontents*` will define the destination label,
saying `\bookmark[dest=toc::label]{\contentsname}` will just add the bookmark entry.

Note: `\blinddocument` is just a quick way to build up a dummy document. It can be removed.

```
\documentclass{memoir}


\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}


\begin{document}

\hypertarget{toc::label}{}
\bookmark[dest=toc::label]{\contentsname}
\tableofcontents* 

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are a Champ Christian. That was exactly what i was looking for, sorry for me bad explanation. Thanks alot :)

Comment: You're welcome. Happy TeXing